# Tags not saving for Joomla category custom component

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

I am developing a Joomla component and using the categories from the joomla Core. The categories are saving properly in the Joomla Administration, but I can't add tags to this categories.. Am I doing something wrong? Or do I need specific code to add tags to the categories for my component?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an entry in the content type table if you want to add tags support in the category. [More Detail](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_Tags_in_an_Extension)

Below is the example code that you can check for refrence to add an entry into content type table. Change `com_example` to your extension.

```
<?php
/** @var JTableContentType $table */
$table  = JTable::getInstance('contenttype');

if ($table)
{
    $table->load(array('type_alias' => 'com_example.category'));

    if (!$table->type_id)
    {
        $data   = array(
            'type_title'        => 'Example Category',
            'type_alias'        => 'com_example.category',
            'table'             => '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__categories","key":"id","type":"Category","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"},'
            . '"common":{"dbtable":"#__ucm_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"}}',
            'rules'             => '',
            'field_mappings'    => '
            {"common":{
            "core_content_item_id":"id",
            "core_title":"title",
            "core_state":"published",
            "core_alias":"alias",
            "core_created_time":"created_time",
            "core_modified_time":"modified_time",
            "core_body":"description",
            "core_hits":"hits",
            "core_publish_up":"null",
            "core_publish_down":"null",
            "core_access":"access",
            "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"null",
            "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language",
            "core_images":"null", "core_urls":"null", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"null", "core_metakey":"metakey",
            "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"parent_id",
            "core_xreference":"null", "asset_id":"asset_id"},
            "special": {
            "parent_id":"parent_id",
            "lft":"lft",
            "rgt":"rgt",
            "level":"level",
            "path":"path",
            "extension":"extension",
            "note":"note"
            }
            }',
            'content_history_options' => '{"formFile":"administrator\/components\/com_categories\/models\/forms\/category.xml",
            "hideFields":["asset_id","checked_out","checked_out_time","version","lft","rgt","level","path","extension"],

            "ignoreChanges":["modified_user_id", "modified_time", "checked_out", "checked_out_time", "version", "hits", "path"],

            "convertToInt":["publish_up", "publish_down"],
"displayLookup":[{"sourceColumn":"created_user_id","targetTable":"#__users","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"name"},
            {"sourceColumn":"access","targetTable":"#__viewlevels","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"title"},
            {"sourceColumn":"modified_user_id","targetTable":"#__users","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"name"},
            {"sourceColumn":"parent_id","targetTable":"#__categories","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"title"}]}',
        );

        $table->bind($data);

        if ($table->check())
        {
            $table->store();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I ma using it in the categories section of Joomla. This should have this functionality..

Comment: @RobertDam By default it supports article categories but for custom one you need to add entries. As there in the documentation -
**Don't forget a category type if you use the Joomla categories API.**

Comment: As a general rule, I do not recommend that any developer manually craft json strings.  Mistakes and typos that damage the integrity of the json can be difficult and frustrating for developers to resolve.  Calling `json_encode()` to generate a viable json string is always the safest way to go. Although dumping a static sql snippet into your post is the most concise way of expressing the necessary code, I think it makes your code more difficult to comment on.

Comment: Please consider expanding your snippet so that researchers can better understand what is happening in that extremely long query.  Perhaps something like this: https://3v4l.org/ZCmr9

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing the same issue I solved it after going through lot of pain. There is no documentation on this if you are using Joomla categories in your component.
@irfan was correct but to make it more easy I feel you can just add a row to the `#__content_types` during installation itself. What I did was I just searched `com_newsfeed` row in joomla database. I came across a newsfeed categories inside `#__content_type`. I replaced the type_title column to my title and type_alias column to `my_extension.category`. And I was able to save the tags. Also router column names to be changed to your router.
Whole SQL code which you need to put inside your sql file is

```
INSERT INTO `#__content_types` (`type_title`, `type_alias`, `table`, `rules`, `field_mappings`, `router`, `content_history_options`) VALUES

('Your Category', 'com_yourcomponent.category', '{"special":{"dbtable":"#__categories","key":"id","type":"Category","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"},"common":{"dbtable":"#__ucm_content","key":"ucm_id","type":"Corecontent","prefix":"JTable","config":"array()"}}', '', '{"common":{"core_content_item_id":"id","core_title":"title","core_state":"published","core_alias":"alias","core_created_time":"created_time","core_modified_time":"modified_time","core_body":"description", "core_hits":"hits","core_publish_up":"null","core_publish_down":"null","core_access":"access", "core_params":"params", "core_featured":"null", "core_metadata":"metadata", "core_language":"language", "core_images":"null", "core_urls":"null", "core_version":"version", "core_ordering":"null", "core_metakey":"metakey", "core_metadesc":"metadesc", "core_catid":"parent_id", "core_xreference":"null", "asset_id":"asset_id"}, "special":{"parent_id":"parent_id","lft":"lft","rgt":"rgt","level":"level","path":"path","extension":"extension","note":"note"}}', 'YourComponentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute', '{"formFile":"administrator\\/components\\/com_categories\\/models\\/forms\\/category.xml", "hideFields":["asset_id","checked_out","checked_out_time","version","lft","rgt","level","path","extension"], "ignoreChanges":["modified_user_id", "modified_time", "checked_out", "checked_out_time", "version", "hits", "path"],"convertToInt":["publish_up", "publish_down"], "displayLookup":[{"sourceColumn":"created_user_id","targetTable":"#__users","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"name"},{"sourceColumn":"access","targetTable":"#__viewlevels","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"title"},{"sourceColumn":"modified_user_id","targetTable":"#__users","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"name"},{"sourceColumn":"parent_id","targetTable":"#__categories","targetColumn":"id","displayColumn":"title"}]}')
```

Note : remember to change the component name in the code. I have given an example code.

Comment: i think you didnt get my words correctly. This is for a custom extension that you are building not related to any joomla core files. You have liberty to change your sql. It wont have any effect on Joomla core files.

Comment: yes in your install.mysql.utf8.sql inside sql folder, you just insert that code at the end. that is what I have written. And I dont think anything is wrong with that approach.

Comment: Ok got your point. My wordings were incorrect, it should be row instead of column. thanks.

Comment: As a general rule, I do not recommend that any developer manually craft json strings.  Mistakes and typos that damage the integrity of the json can be difficult and frustrating for developers to resolve.  Calling `json_encode()` to generate a viable json string is always the safest way to go. Although dumping a static sql snippet into your post is the most concise way of expressing the necessary code, I think it makes your code more difficult to comment on.

Comment: Please consider expanding your snippet so that researchers can better understand what is happening in that extremely long query.  Perhaps something like this: https://3v4l.org/ZCmr9

Comment: I have just expanded the answer given by @Irfan. I have also referenced his answer. So researchers will understand from the above answer. So I have not repeated it. My intention was to show another path where you can do the same using sql query.